# Stop Click, Enter and Arrow Binds for child of accorion header

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

So I would like to put a contenteditable field in the header of an Accordion from JQueryUI, however, when I try to bind an event to that sub object, the binds of the accordion take precedence even when I attempt to unbind or block inheritance.

```
<div class="accord">
    <div>
        <div class="theHead" >
            <span class="ignoreAccordBinds" contenteditable="true">Edit Me</span>
        </div>
        <div class="theBody">
        SomeBody
        </div>
    </div>
            ...
```

I would like the code above to ignore all accordion actions when doing any action within the span.

I've tried

```
     $(".ignoreAccordBinds").keypress(function(e){
          e.stopPropagation();
      });
   $(".accord").find(".ignoreAccordBinds").unbind();
```

Neither seem to help.

I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P93E6/5/) of my issue. If you attempt to use the right arrow key to move the cursor(caret) on one of the titles, the accordion instead selects another div. If you attempt to press enter, it only opens/closes them instead of inserting a line break.

Anyone have any ideas here?

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dJbS3/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `unbind()` and register the keydown handler

```
$(".ignoreAccordBinds").keydown(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dJbS3/)

The [keypress event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/keypress) is fired when a key is pressed down and that key normally produces a character value - so keys like arrow does not fire it

Comment: Ah, Yes, that did it! should have thought about keydown instead of keypress. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$(".ignoreAccordBinds").keypress(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

Your syntax is incorrect.

```
  $(".ignoreAccordBinds").keypress()(function(e)
                                  ^
```

You don't need parenthesis here.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/P93E6/6/)

Comment: Right, mine was typoed, but this does not work either way. I will, however, correct it in my fiddle and example. Thanks

Comment: @Jeff, use `return false;`

Comment: Updated with the return false, still no dice: http://jsfiddle.net/P93E6/7/ Also, pressing the arrow keys in your demo still does not move the cursor and pressing enter does not add a line break.(really if I could just get the arrow keys working I'd be happy)